# how to convert tensorflow op in pb file?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I download a pretrain mobilenet-v1.pb file, but it force input image to 224x224 because the model of it has a 7x7 avg_pooling operation.

Actually I want to inference a 300x300 image, as I see, I must convert the avg_pooling op to reduce_mean op, and get a new .pb file. But I don't know how to do it, anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll need more information, but the change you want to do isn't trivial, because all the weights will be in a particular shape. You'll have to retrain the network and export it as a new pb file

Comment: thanks for you ans! Normally you are right, but I just want to test the model's inference time with different input size, actually I am testing the capability of TFLite in raspberry-pi3. So I won't retrain the network now, but maybe will do it in the future.

Comment: Make changes to the network and just start a training. Stop it after the first checkpoint itself. Generate the model file and test it out.